# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@a' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to update a column in SQL but I get this Error..

Code:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update details set Available='Yes' where License='@a'", cn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", num);
            cn.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
```

Comment: remove the single quotes around `@a`: `where License=@a`

Comment: By putting your parameter in single quotes you are comparing to a literal string that is the name of the parameter and not the value of the parameter.  It's like expecting `int i = 3; string s = "i";` to result in `s` being "3" instead of "i".

Comment: Slight detour but you should read this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from around the @a

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update details set Available='Yes' where License=@a", cn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", num);
            cn.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
```